# Conflict error while loading a conda environment from a local file

Tags: python, anaconda

this might be a noob question.
I was trying to load a conda environment form a local file and I got loads of conflict errors like these:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package scipy conflicts for:
keras-base==2.2.2=py36_0 -> scipy[version='>=0.14']
keras-preprocessing==1.0.2=py36_1 -> scipy[version='>=0.14']
scipy==1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1
keras==2.2.2=0 -> keras-base=2.2.2 -> scipy[version='>=0.14']
scikit-learn==0.19.1=py36hae9bb9f_0 -> scipy

Package hdf5 conflicts for:
opencv==3.4.2=py36h40b0b35_0 -> hdf5[version='>=1.8.20,hdf5==1.8.20=hac2f561_1
keras-applications==1.0.4=py36_1 -> h5py -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.1,=1.10.2,=1.10.4,=1.10.6,=1.8.20,=1.8.18,=1.8.18,h5py==2.8.0=py36hf7173ca_2 -> hdf5[version='>=1.8.20,keras-base==2.2.2=py36_0 -> h5py -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.1,=1.10.2,=1.10.4,=1.10.6,=1.8.20,=1.8.18,=1.8.18,opencv-contrib==3.3.1=py36_1 -> hdf5

Package yaml conflicts for:
yaml==0.1.7=hc54c509_2
pyyaml==3.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0 -> yaml[version='>=0.1.7,keras-base==2.2.2=py36_0 -> pyyaml -> yaml[version='>=0.1.7,=0.2.5,
Package cycler conflicts for:
matplotlib==2.2.3=py36hd159220_0 -> cycler[version='>=0.10']
cycler==0.10.0=py36h009560c_0

Package tk conflicts for:
tk==8.6.8=hfa6e2cd_0
pillow==5.2.0=py36h08bbbbd_0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.7,
Package packaging conflicts for:
python==3.6.6=hea74fb7_0 -> pip -> packaging
nbconvert==5.3.1=py36_0 -> bleach -> packaging
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "loading from a local file"? Are you actually installing from a yaml? If so, how does it look like?

Comment: I'm importing from Anaconda Navigator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your `environment.yml` file.

---

Here is a generic procedure for resolving such versionitis issues.

Replace version pins such as

```
  - scikit-learn == 0.19.1
```

with unpinned deps:

```
  - scikit-learn
```

Run `$ conda env update` and see it succeed.
(If need be, delete the environment entirely before doing that,
so ancient pins won't cause trouble for the version solver.)

View the output of `$ conda list` to learn about
successfully installed version numbers.
If desired, put the pins back.
Or consider expressing them like this:

```
  - scikit-learn >= 0.19.1
```

That would give `conda` the flexibility to use more modern (compatible!)
versions of dependencies as time goes on.

---

It is worth your while to uprev such deps,
so conda has fewer combinations to quickly consider.
Dealing with deps released over the last three months
is a much smaller combinatorial explosion
compared to dealing with deps from the last three years.

---

Issue queries like
https://anaconda.org/search?q=scikit-learn
to find that you might e.g. prefer version 1.1.1 over 0.19.1.